Python project is failing to import local packages
I am creating a py project that the programs are related but dont interact with one another but share a lot of common code.  My structure is below.  Inside of app.py I can import functions from common.example import whatever and it works.  When I copy the code into sendApp.py and receiveApp.py the code fails.
no module name common.  What I am trying to achieve is having the apps share the common modules among others. Printing sys.path in sendApp.py contains the path testApp\send\ adding the __init__.py to testApp didn't matter.  I will start these with shell scripts so would adding the testApp to path be the way to go? Or is there a better way to achieve my goal.
testApp
|___app.py
|___common
|   |
|   |_example.py
|
|___sendApp
|   |
|   |__sendApp.py
|   |__init__.py
|
|___ReceiveApp
    |
    |__receiveApp.py
    |__init__.py  


If you add testApp to your path, then from common.example import whatever should work.

so the in shell script I should just add the path PATH=$PATH:/whatever/testApp then fire up sendApp.py and receiveApp.py

No.  You want PYTHONPATH, not PATH.  PYTHONPATH is for python modules.  PATH is for executable programs.

I think you can try some really easy ways:

You could structure your project as a Python package and include an init.py in the testApp directory to make it a proper package.

use relative imports if you're packaging the entire project as a Python package



I will give this a shot as well.  I did try this earlier, however I might not have set everything up correctly.  I will pursue this as well.
